# Samsung ChatOn API throws RESULT_CODE_FAIL_EXCEPTION

Tags: android, sdk, chat, samsung-mobile

I am trying to integrate Samsung SDK in my android project. All I need to do is to send a text message with url to the ChatOn app using the Client ChatON API. On executing this call:

```
    int nResult = MessageAPI.sendTextMessageWithURL (getApplicationContext(), "Hello", 
                    "http://www.chaton.com");
```

It returns 3 (RESULT_CODE_FAIL_EXCEPTION) with this error message: "Exception!!\nPlease, check argument"

I couldn't find any relevant documentation also on what kind of exceptions can be thrown and reasons behind them. Does anyone know more about what is the problem because of which this error code (3) is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the official application of Samsung ChatON. Utility api having a method to know, Is ChatON is install or not.
The Utility API Class provides typical tools that are useful for application development by using Client APIs.

```
  UtilityAPI.isChatONInstalled(Context context)
```

Utility api also provide the method by which you can get the download link of ChatON application.

```
   UtilityAPI.openChatONDownloadPage(Context context)
```

for more infromation, please see this [link](http://img-developer.samsung.com/contents/cmm/ChatON_UI_Library_Guide_v1.2.2%28Public%29_ENG.pdf)